# PayPal IPN HTML code for recurring payments with a different first payment

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm trying to find the PayPal IPN HTML variables that I would need to set up recurring payments where the first payment is different that the recurring payments. I'm really unclear as to whether subscriptions or recurring code is the best for this, but if someone can help that would be appreciated. I'm very close with the subscription code, if I could find a way to add a shipping fee and a handling fee that would be good too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express Checkout Recurring Payments (using the CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile API call) will allow you to specify an INITAMT. Alternatively, you can just call DoExpressCheckoutPayment before calling CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile and set the PROFILESTARTDATE to a date in the future.

Either way will work with Express Checkout.
Have a look at https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_ECRecurringPayments and https://www.x.com/docs/DOC-1168

Note: The latter API doc may list parameters that are not available to you, as these are for Website Payments Pro customers only (e.g. the ability to supply a card number directly).